# Update an existing app

Tags: heroku, django-cms

I have a Django-cms website running online on Heroku. I pushed this online from a device at work. Now I'm at home and I have same project running on my machine and I did some changes and I wanna push them live on the same link.
What I need to do?

```
git init
git add .
heroku create
```

that gonna create an other link , but I wanna push my amends on the same link I have already.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I didn't add my public key I did:

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get add the Heroku git remote to your new application. Grab the app's git repo from the apps page in Dashboard and then do;

```
git remote add heroku <git repo here>
```

and then you'll be able to push as you are able to on the other machine.

Comment: I have try:  heroku git:remote -a quiet-coast-9871 and I have  !    Git remote heroku already exists
but then when I do : git push heroku master
I have : fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: I have tried git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:quiet-coast-9871.git
and git remote add heroku quiet-coast-9871
it says fatal: remote heroku already exists.
but then I cannot push